# Way of Solving Advent of Code using BlackBox environment (Component-Pascal)

Tags: oberon, component-pascal

I'm looking for examples on how to solve problems with Black Box Component Builder (BBCB). However, all examples including the documentation (tutorial and samples) are very constricted to the environment.

for example what i look for is how to solve the problem (i.e. https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/1) using BBCB. I know how to solve it in other languages (Common-Lisp, Forth, C, ...etc). But how to target the problem from within BBCB. is there a standard approach? is there a way of thinking? or how this language can shape my mind in a different way.

I tried documentation (inside BBCB), i read and played with Wirth's book (Algorithms and Data Structure) as well as Computing Fundamentals by Stanley. but these examples tried are constricted to their respective environments command line for Oberon2 and BBCB for CP

Comment: I think you need to be more specific in your problem description. Are you having problems with the language Component Pascal or with the programming environment? What is your concrete problem?

Comment: In traditional pascal/oberon2 Linux based compilers (mostly text file based). you open your fav. editor, code the solution, read in input and test the code. In BBCB, there is docu documents, Mod files do I need to only use Mod Files (component pascal files) or both and copy the sample input into a docu file, read its content and solve the Day 1 problem as a subsystem structured BBCB project. hope it clarify my intent (ie maximize BBCB environment components usage to the benefit of the programmer and the solution). I'm working on a try to use both and will post my trial on github with link here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a module In, that is usually used in BlackBox Component Builder for some educational examples like Advent of Code.

So I prepared the demonstration module of using it for Day1 example.

```
MODULE AdventofcodeDay1;

IMPORT In, Log;

PROCEDURE Do*;
CONST undefined = -1;
VAR firstDigit, lastDigit, twoDigitNumber, res, digit: INTEGER; char: CHAR;
BEGIN
    In.Open;
    res := 0; firstDigit := undefined; lastDigit := undefined;
    WHILE In.Done DO
        In.Char(char);
        IF (char = 0DX) OR ~In.Done THEN
            IF firstDigit # undefined THEN
                twoDigitNumber := firstDigit * 10 + lastDigit;
                Log.Tab; Log.Int(twoDigitNumber);
                res := res + twoDigitNumber
            END;
            firstDigit := undefined; lastDigit := undefined;
            Log.Ln
        ELSE
            digit := ORD(char) - 30H;
            IF (firstDigit = undefined) & (digit >= 0) & (digit <= 9) THEN
                firstDigit := digit;
                lastDigit := firstDigit
            ELSIF (firstDigit # undefined) & (digit >= 0) & (digit <= 9) THEN
                lastDigit := digit
            END;
            Log.Char(char)
        END
    END;
    Log.Int(res); Log.Ln;
END Do;

END AdventofcodeDay1.


^Q AdventofcodeDay1.Do

1abc2
pqr3stu8vwx
a1b2c3d4e5f
treb7uchet
```

What you need, is to select the text bellow the command and press commander ^Q which can be inserted by Ctrl+q  (if you read some documentation for BBCP, you can know how to use commanders already to start exported procedures).

Comment: So, does it mean that whatever you select becomes the input provided to the procedure Do thru module In? (I've never used the module In)

Comment: The beginning of selection will become begin of input "stream" and it can read then till end of document. So end of selection doesn't used.